# PHP Webhook Request

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, webhooks

I am running a WordPress site with a WooCommerce checkout. At the checkout page I am using the webhook *woocommerce_thankyou* as a boarding point for my code. At this Point I am selecting some data from the new my order to send the data to another website via a webhook.
I integrated the code over a custom WordPress plugin. At the moment the webhook gives me back this following error: "DigiMember - Webhook Checkout (#1): the E-Mail-Adress would not send as GET- or POST-Parameter."

What could be the problem?

```php
<?php
    function test ($order_id) {
?>

<span>
            woocommerce_thankyou
             <?php echo $order_id;
             $order=wc_get_order($order_id);
             echo $order->get_meta('digi_first_name');
             echo $order->get_meta('digi_last_name');
             echo $order->get_meta('digi_email');

             ?>
        </span>
        <?php
//The url you wish to send the POST request to
$url = 'https://traumjob-campus.de/member?dm_webhook=1_DCqtx6Xre1oM7tuKyon5rVzAIUWvVVXofMqTRQjE9JVDgf7gLI3M198bIeD5';

//The data you want to send via POST
$fields = [
    'digi_first_name'      => 'user',
    'digi_last_name' => 'test',
    'digi_email'         => 'test@user.de'
];

//url-ify the data for the POST
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//So that curl_exec returns the contents of the cURL; rather than echoing it
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Try setting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` and then `exit();` after you echo your `$result`.  This may provide you with more information.

Comment: Check. This time the error code is like this: "moved permanently, the document has moved here" when I click on "here" its the same error code as before "DigiMember - Webhook Checkout (#1): the E-Mail-Adress would not send as GET- or POST-Parameter."

Comment: It's possible since the [error message](https://traumjob-campus.de/member/?dm_webhook=1_DCqtx6Xre1oM7tuKyon5rVzAIUWvVVXofMqTRQjE9JVDgf7gLI3M198bIeD5) states that you are not sending the expected email field name, that this is causing the error so double check the documentation. Also, since there is a redirect, you should include `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` in the curl init.